# Version Control and Deploy Rails Project with cPanel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, ssh, capistrano

In my server, what option i got is a basic unlimited server can host unlimited rails project
possible to manage gem because it is using cpanel latest version with a ssh 
now my confuse is ,

how can i use the no ssh feature in the cpanel and ease my deployment ?
i don't know is that possible to use the capistrano and git with it
any guidance for this ? to make it possible to update with git push feature
i never deploy anything before ,
i tried to use heroku but i don't know why many user can make their file fit the 5mb space...
my project is now 30% at progress but the space used was 14mb...

so, i bought a cheap standard web server with cpanel . any one could help me in this case ?
usually how you guy deploy and where you deploy ?

recently one guy gave me a link for the github deployment, is that possible to make github use in the cpanel server ?
i mean like host and push the file into github and then link to the personal server ?
anyway, thx for person who reply me recently ^.^

i just develop for hobby...any cheap rails server suggest ?
Thx a lot for reply~

Comment: You have all the tools you need.  Capistrano supports git since version 2.1.  Take a look at some of the tutorials on the website. http://www.capify.org

Answer (score 2):

You could also try heroku (www.heroku.com) as a hosting platform. It has a simple deployment workflow that uses git.

Comment: but its too expensive

Answer (score 1):

Unelss you've done it already, you'll need to [install git](http://kylecordes.com/2008/04/30/git-windows-go/) on your local machine.

Here's a [bit about capistrano](http://github.com/guides/deploying-with-capistrano) too.

Capistrano is basically a series of scripts (that you run from your local machine)  that get your code and put it on your web server(s). You can configure capistrano to either check out your code from git on the production server, or to copy your code from your local machine.

Comment: i found your link is useful~
especially KC site, he almost introduce everything must know before deploy~
Thank you